Laravel Eloquent Order By Coalesce
I am having issues using a coalesce inside an orderby to order on 2 relationship columns. Here is the code in question:
$productList = Product::select(
    'ItemName'
    ,'ItemCode'
    ,'QryGroup64'
    ,'U_SDB_Image_File'
)->active();

if ($this->search) {
    $productList = $productList->where('ItemName',  'LIKE', '%'. str_replace(" ", "%", $this->search) . '%');
}

if ($this->category) {
    $productList = $productList->where('U_SDB_SALES_GROUP', $this->category);
}
            
// Handle the order by. It is done like this because of the pagination
if ($this->orderBy == 'ItemNameASC') {
    $productList = $productList->with('customerSpecialPrice', 'bandAPrice', 'itemStock', 'itemsPurchased8Weeks')
        ->orderBy('ItemName');
} elseif ($this->orderBy == 'ItemNameDESC') {
    $productList = $productList->with('customerSpecialPrice', 'bandAPrice', 'itemStock', 'itemsPurchased8Weeks')
        ->orderBy('ItemName', 'desc');
} elseif ($this->orderBy == 'PriceASC') {
    $productList = $productList->with('itemStock', 'itemsPurchased8Weeks')
        ->withAggregate('bandAPrice', 'Price')
        ->withAggregate('customerSpecialPrice', 'Price')
        ->orderByRaw("COALESCE(customer_special_price_price,  band_a_price_price)");
}

$productList = $productList->paginate($this->perPage);

This is for product browsing. Every item has a Band A price (default sell out price). There is another table that has our quoted products which means that there isn't always a special price for every item.
Now, if I do:
->orderBy("customer_special_price_price");
, This works to an extent. All of the special prices are in order but at the end of the list (due to null being pulled first). This is why I am wanting to use a COALESCE.
Errors I have gotten:
When trying: ->orderByRaw("COALESCE(customer_special_price_price, band_a_price_price)");, it gives me the error Invalid column name 'customer_special_price_price'.
Below is the query it is trying to run when it shows this error:
select
    top 20 [ ItemName ],
    [ ItemCode ],
    [ QryGroup64 ],
    [ U_SDB_Image_File ],
    (
        select
            top 1 Price
        from
            [ ITM1 ]
        where
            [ OITM ].[ ItemCode ] = [ ITM1 ].[ ItemCode ]
            and [ PriceList ] = 25
    ) as [ band_a_price_price ],
    (
        select
            top 1 Price
        from
            [ OSPP ]
        where
            [ OITM ].[ ItemCode ] = [ OSPP ].[ ItemCode ]
            and [ CardCode ] = CF000097 - F
    ) as [ customer_special_price_price ]
from
    [ OITM ]
where
    SellItem = 'Y'
    AND (
        QryGroup64 = 'N'
        OR OnHand > 0
    )
    and [ ItemName ] LIKE % carling %
order by
    COALESCE(customer_special_price_price, band_a_price_price)

Why is orderBy picking up the column created via the withAggregate but the orderByRaw isnt?

Have you tried running that query directly in the database?

@IGP After formatting it in SQL Server Management Studio, it also gave the same error. I am used to developing without a framework with PHP and would build this query using LEFT JOINS which would've allowed a COALESCE in the orderBy. I am trying to do everything right in this Laravel Project. I dont understand that I can do orderBy('customer_special_price_price') and that work, but orderByRaw doesnt like it. Ive been looking around and I can't put a COALESCE inside a orderBy(). Do I need to bite the bullet and use a join() & leftJoin() rather than eloquent relationships?

I'm unfamiliar with SQL Server's quirks. I tried to do something like that with mysql and the query worked as expected.

Well the columns generated by WithAggregate are not directly available to be used in an orderByRaw clause, that is, the main query does not recognize them because they are not a direct part of the set, what you could do is use or replace it with joinsub or use orderBy instead of COALESCE.
